# Load URL is not properly loaded on Apps' page

Tags: bigcommerce

The app page located under the apps tab is not rendering correctly. The request is coming in fine with the signed payload but the iframe (that loads the load URL) renders an empty page every time I visit the app page.

I try opening the exact page in a new tab and it's rendering fine:

https://staging02.pathdefender.com/app/bigcommerce/load?signed_payload=eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjo0NDA2MTYsImVtYWlsIjoiZGVubmlzQHRydXN0ZWRzaXRlLmNvbSJ9LCJjb250ZXh0Ijoic3RvcmVzL24yaXMwYTRjIiwic3RvcmVfaGFzaCI6Im4yaXMwYTRjIiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNDQyODYyNjQzLjk4MzgyNTR9.MjFmNWFhZGU4ZjkyN2NkY2I4YzEwOTkyNzdjYjA4ZGU0OWE5MjU4MzRlZTYwNDc4ODNhNzU2MDliYWJlMmZlZA==

Do you know what's wrong with the page?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?